# PS cmdlet New-AzAksCluster will trigger SP creation ignoring the -EnableManagedIdentity option

Tags: powershell, azure-aks

Note: This is my first time posting here so apologies if this isn`t the right platform for these type of questions or if the context is not clear. Any feedback is welcome!

At a high level, I`m struggling to create a public AKS cluster using the PS cmdlet New-AzAksCluster because every time it runs it will attempt to create a Service Principal even if I supply the options -EnableManagedIdentity & -AssignIdentity

[New-AzAksCluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1L6W.png)

My expectation would be that it will use the assigned Managed Identity instead. Reason I`m expecting that is, because a) when I use the az cli to create the same cluster with the same options, it will not create an sp but instead propagate the Az AD roles to the identity it is given:

[az aks create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owaIY.png)

b) according to the docs it shouldn`t behave like that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/new-azakscluster?view=azps-10.4.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity

> AKS doesn't automatically create a service principal, so you have to create one. Clusters that use a service principal eventually expire, and the service principal must be renewed to avoid impacting cluster authentication with the identity. Managing service principals adds complexity, so it's easier to use managed identities instead.

I tested it using the Powershell on my localhost, the one integrated with VSCode as well as the Azure CloudShell (also with different accounts, tenants and subscriptions) and found that it behaves the same. The fact that I`m Owner, GlobalAdmin (or any user role that has sufficient permissions) doesn`t seem to matter either. I also tried to delete the 'acsServicePrincipal.json' -file to no avail.

I just wanted to bounce some ideas before I raise a github issue.

Comment: Please refer to -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity and https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/18139 https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/18385

Comment: After a workaround on your issue, I found that using `New-AzAksCluster` will always create a service principal even though we have not given. Hence if you want to create cluster using managed identity, I suggest use `az aks` CLI commands. @Gabor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `New-AzAKSCluster` PowerShell command does not allow you to enable Managed Identity without creating or taking an existing service principal and the fix is still in implementation as per the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/18385) merged issue.

As a fix for your issue, I found that calling `New-AzAksCluster` will always generate a service principal even if we have not provided one. As a result, if you want to create a cluster with managed identity, I recommend making use of the [`az aks create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-create) CLI command.

*System managed identity:*

```bash
az aks create -g <resourcegroup> -n <Clustername> --enable-managed-identity
```

[image]

*User managed identity:*

```bash
az aks create -g xxx -n jahuserCluster --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity <resourceID of user identity>
```

[image]